# Why is this.markerArray undefined? understanding "this"

Tags: angular, typescript, this

I am still getting my understanding around 'this'. In the following context, i keep getting the error "this.markerArray is undefined". But I have declared markerArray as a variable globally so I am rather confused.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-open-street-map',
  templateUrl: './open-street-map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./open-street-map.component.css']
})
export class OpenStreetMapComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() private add = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() private edit = new EventEmitter<number>();
  artworkList: Artwork[];
  map;
  //declared it here
  markerArray = [];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  });

  buildMarkers(artworkList) {
    for (let artwork of artworkList) {
      const marker = this.buildPopup(artwork);
      this.markers.push(marker);
    }
    console.log("marker", marker);
    console.log("markerArray", this.markerArray);
  }
}
```

I have obviously removed a lot of the code from this ts page! the point is to fill up the `markerArray`, I got your earlier point of initializing it,which i did, but for some reason all array inputs are "undefined" still?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to initialize it with empty array

```
  markerArray = [];
```

Comment: Thank you! But I thought if I just leave it like that it meant "any"! I didn't initialize map either, why is that working?